# unable to fetch req.user.isAdmin

Tags: node.js

> authorize middleware..

```
const authorize = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.header('x-auth-token');
    if(!token) return res.status(401).json({message: "Access denied!! No token provided"});
    try{
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
        req.user = decoded;

        next();

    }catch(ex){
         return res.json({message: "Invalid token"})
        }
}
```

> isAdmin middleware...

```
const isAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const {isAdmin} = req.user;
        console.log(req.user)
        if(!isAdmin) return res.json({message: "forbidden"});
    }
    catch(ex) {
        res.json(ex.message)
    }

    next();
}
```

> dcr route to post dce report

```
const express = require('express')
const {authorize, isAdmin} = require('../middleware/authentication')
const router = express.Router();
const {postDcr} = require('../controllers/reportController');

router.post('/smDcr', authorize, isAdmin, postDcr);


module.exports = router;
```

> scr controller for posting daily call report

```
const {Dcr} = require('../util/database');
exports.postDcr = async(req, res, next) => {

    try{
        const dcr = await Dcr.create(req.body);
        return res.status(200).json({dcr});


    }catch(ex){
        return res.json({message:" DCR creation failed"});

    }



};
```

> when logging to console I am able to feth full user object but when using >>req.user.isAdmin its undefined.

Answer (score 0):

## set user value in the callback function

```
jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET,(err,decoded)=>{
if(!err && decoded){
req.user = decoded.user;
next();
}
else{
 return err;
}
});
```

Comment: Hi Virendra, Thanks for your response but still req.user.isAdmin is undefined though user property is available on request object while logging to console or json response. Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `smreports` FROM `prelude`
Server connected and running on port 3000
{ user:
   { id: 4,
     name: 'Santosh',
     isAdmin: true,
     email: 'santosh@gmail.com',
     image: null },
  iat: 1568212037 } undefined

Comment: ahhh, i got your issue so user is the part on decoded object and when you do const {is Admin} = req.user, it will give undefined because user obejct is in inside object 
assign req.user from decoded object because decoded object is not user object

" req.user = decoded.user " //` i edited the upper code`.